# read another node while traversing xml for PDF generation through page2fo.xsl

Tags: aem, sling, apache-fop

I am trying OOTB PDF rewriter component and able to generate a PDF for simple use-case however it is not working in some scenarios.

Scenario1:able to generate the PDF when the page has data stored in a single node.
Scenario2: unable to generate the PDF when the paged is referencing multiple nodes.

```
    <xsl:template match="jcr:content">
    <xsl:if test="@articleTitle">
        <fo:block font-size="30pt" 
            text-align="start" font-family="DinProLight">
            <xsl:value-of select="@articleTitle" />
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="@publishDate">
        <fo:block font-size="18pt" color="#777777" text-align="start" font-family="georgia;" 
        font-style="italic" padding-bottom="9px">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(@publishDate,9,2),'-',substring(@publishDate,7,2),substring(@publishDate,0,5))" />
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="@authorPath"> 
        <fo:block font-size="18pt" color="#777777"  padding="3px" text-align="start">
            <!--Below Code works fine -->
            <fo:external-graphic src="url('sling://etc/designs/XXXX/images/logo.jpg')" content-type="content-type:image/jpeg"/>         
            <!--Below Code Fails -->
            <xsl:value-of select="sling://content/XXXX/en/perspectives/tst_artcl/jcr:content@fullName"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>


    <xsl:if test="@noOfViews">
        <fo:block font-size="11pt" color="#777777" text-align="right" font-family="arial" padding-bottom="9px" border-bottom="1px solid #777777">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@noOfViews,' Views')" />
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I cannot fully understand your question. you expect to have the same xsl for two different content structures?

Comment: No basically my one content structure has another content embedded inside. e.g. an employee bio page having address coming from another node and contact information coming from another.

Comment: I have changed the approach of PDF generation as we found a few other use cases which couldn't be solved by Apache FOP.              I used phantomjs to generate my pdf on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the PDF generation by default work by using the default xml rendering of your nodes (content/app/page.xml), but since you need to get information from more than one node I recommend to just create your own xml.

-Register a servlet with PDF extension and your resourceType of choice and render a xml that contains all the information you need and with the most convenient structure. (you can use the resourceResolver inside the servlet to access any node you need).

Then the pdf rewriter will use your xml representation instead of the default one.

for example

```
@SlingServlet(
    description = "Employee PDF",
    extensions = { "pdf" },
    resourceTypes = { "greatapp/page/employee" },
    methods = { "GET" })
 public class EmployeePDFServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

   protected void doGet(final SlingHttpServletRequest request, final SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
     //generate an xml here
    }
 }
```